# Is there a way to format a MacBook hard drive from Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, windows, disk-format

I have an old mid-2008 MacBook, used to work fine until one day I decided to install CloudReady on it, it worked like garbage.

I tried all the cmd+[whatever] options to get a boot menu and rollback to macOS but nothing works, now I removed the hard-drive and plugged it (with an adapter) in my Windows PC.

What can I do from here knowing that I don't have access to any Mac right now? Also keep in mind that my end goal is to install Ubuntu on this Mac because the new macOS will be super slow.

Comment: Create an Ubuntu USB installer on Windows and use it to install on the Mac.